# Software to model bioheat transfer?

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, open-source

I am looking for software that can be used to model bioheat transfer, which is heat transfer in living systems (e.g. melting an ice cube in your hand or a cool breeze blowing on a hot summer's day). Alternatively, a bioheat package or module for something like Blender, FreeCAD or any other recommended software.

If such a software or package does not exist, what could I use to potentially model living tissue myself (tissue simulation, fluid simulations for veins, etc.)?

If possible, it would be nice if the software were free. It would also be nice if the software could run on Linux, but not necessary.